# Ring/Field isomorphism before knowing it's a ring/field

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory

If I know $F$ is a ring/field, and I have $G$ (unkown), but I can find a bijective map:
$$\Phi:F\to G$$ such that
$\forall a,b\in F.\;\Phi(a+b) =\Phi(a)+\Phi(b).\;\Phi(ab) = \Phi(a)\Phi(b)$
Does that mean G is automatically a ring/field and is isomorphic to $F$? If so what's the name of the theorem, if not any counter-examples? Thank you.

Comment: So you know that $G$ has two operations, you just don't know that those make $G$ a ring a priori?

Comment: If all you know about $G$ is that there is a bijection $\Phi:F\rightarrow G$, then you can define $+$ and $\cdot$ in $G$ to be just what you have, and then $F$ and $G$ will be isomorphic.

Comment: The is called transport of structure by $\Phi$ from the ring/field $F$ to the set $G$.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Yes.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen I see. thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since a field is a ring, we will just use the word ring. We can now show that $G$ satisfies the axioms for a ring. For any two elements $\Phi(a), \Phi(b)$ we can form two more $\Phi(a+b), \Phi(ab)$. And we also have the distributivity, so it must be a ring as well. We also have that if $F$ is a field, then $G$ is a field because they are isomorphic rings.